# Exit out of the bash script from mongo shell if a condition passes

Tags: linux, mongodb, bash, shell, mongo-shell

I'm writing a bash script. I need to Exit out of the bash script from the mongo shell if a condition passes. I tried `quit(0)` but it only exits out of the shell and continues with the rest of the bash script.

```
mongo ${ssl_mode} --quiet <<EOF  //connecting to mongo
    {
      if(array.member!== 1) {
           print("Successful Validation.");
           quit(0);                                
      } else {
         //some code
      }
EOF

//rest of the bash script
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the script exit when `mongo` returns success:

```sh
mongo ${ssl_mode} --quiet <<EOF && exit
    {
      if(array.member!== 1) {
           print("Successful Validation.");
           quit(0);      // exit mongo shell and exit bash script 
      } else {
         //some code
         quit(1);        // exit mongo shell but continue bash script
      }
EOF
```

Comment: What exactly does quit(1) and quit(0) do? When you say quit(1), does the rest of the bash script continue? or does the code in the mongo shell continue?

Comment: `quit(1)` exits the mongo shell with exit code `1`. Bash can then check this exit code to see whether or not it should exit as well. In this case, the bash script exits if mongo returns 0, and continues if mongo exits with anything else

Comment: Note that it's the `&& exit` in the first line that makes the `bash` script exit, not anything inside the `mongo` script. (`quit(0)` is what makes `mongo` have an exit status that tells the `bash` script to execute the command following `&&`.)

Comment: (The syntax highlighter incorrectly, IMO, makes `&& exit` look like part of the here document.)

Answer (score 1):

Check the return code of the mongo shell:

```
mongo ${ssl_mode} --quiet <<EOF  //connecting to mongo
    {
      if(array.member!== 1) {
           print("Successful Validation.");
           quit(33);                                
      } else {
         //some code
      }
EOF
if [[ $? -eq 33 ]] ; then
   exit 0
fi
```

Comment: There's little reason to break convention and use a non-zero exit status to indicate success.

Comment: Fully agree, but I wanted to visualize the principle of return code.